# AWS CDK synth errors out for a Code Pipeline with CodeBuildStep

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to implement an AWS Code-Pipeline using aws-cdk v2. Here is my code which does not have any errors but errors out while doing a cdk synth.

```
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, "MyPipeline", {
  pipelineName: "my-pipeline",
  synth: new CodeBuildStep("SynthStep", {
    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(repo, "mainline"),
    buildEnvironment: {
      computeType: CodeBuild.ComputeType.MEDIUM,
      buildImage: CodeBuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0,
    },
    partialBuildSpec: buildSpec,
    commands: [],
    role: codeBuildSynthRole,
  }),
  crossAccountKeys: true,
  selfMutation: true,
  dockerEnabledForSelfMutation: true,
});
```

I get an error - 'Only one build spec is allowed to specify artifacts.' What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The issue is not in the code you provided - it's either in the source step or the synth buildspec.

Answer (score 1):

You did not show your `buildSpec` but I suspect it includes artifacts. `CodeBuildStep` creates its own `artifacts` element. If you view the CDK source by control-clicking in your IDE on the `partialBuildSpec`, it says:

```
    /**
     * Additional configuration that can only be configured via BuildSpec
     *
     * You should not use this to specify output artifacts; those
     * should be supplied via the other properties of this class, otherwise
     * CDK Pipelines won't be able to inspect the artifacts.
     *
     * Set the `commands` to an empty array if you want to fully specify
     * the BuildSpec using this field.
     */
```